# Customize the listing grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I have to customize the listing grid in my own module,[image]
I want to show  group all the slot list day name e.g. monday - 12:00:00,13:00:00

Comment: Are you using UI grid?

Comment: yes,I am using ui grid

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to renderer `day` field in UI grid.**

Add `<Vendor>\<Module>\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customday` class in day field like this

```
<column name="day" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customday">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">day</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Now create **`Customday.php`** at

`<Vendor>\<Module>\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customday.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Customday extends Column
{

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {   
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $day = $items['day'];
                $startTime = $items['start_time'];
                $endTime = $items['end_time'];

                $items['day'] = $day."-".$startTime.",".$endTime; //OUTPUT: monday - 12:00:00,13:00:00           
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```